# Find unique sequences within dna strings

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file which contains bunch of sequences. The strings have a prefix of AAGCTT and a suffix of GCGGCCGC.

Between these two pattern lies unique sequences. I want to find these sequences and count their occurrence.

Example below

***AAGCTT***CTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCG***GCGGCCGC***

String CTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCG is present 1000 times.

Comment: 1) The problem statement in this question is too *imprecise* for an *accurate* answer.  Socowi's point about "unique" is just one of the problems.  While some people are willing to guess what you mean, we / you don't know if they have guessed correctly.  2) Aren't there off-the-shelf solutions for doing this kind of searching / matching on DNA sequences?  At scale?  More efficiently than cobbling something together using shell scripts?

Comment: 3) You might actually get a better answer in https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ ... where people who do this kind of thing professionally are more likely to hang out.  (Unless this is just a programming exercise ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd divide the problem into these subproblems:

- Extract all sequences between `AAGCTT` and `GCGGCCGC`:
  `grep -Po 'AAGCTT\K.*?(?=GCGGCCGC)'`.
  <sub>`-P` is a GNU extension. If your implementation of `grep` does not support it use `pcregrep`.

  **Assumption:** The sequences to be extracted never contain `AAGCTT`/`GCGGCCGC` except at the beginning/end.</sub>
- Count the found sequences:
  `sort | uniq -c`

Putting everything together, we end up with:

```
grep -Po 'AAGCTT\K.*?(?=GCGGCCGC)' yourInputFile | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard (impossible?) to assess whether this will work for you, given the sample size. My one-liner assumes one sequence per line, lines defined by unix line endings.

```
echo "AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCGGCGGCCGC" | awk '{a[gensub( /AAGCTT(.*)GCGGCCGC/,"\\1",1,$0)]++}END{for(i in a){print i" is present "a[i]" times"}}'
CTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCG is present 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
awk '/^AAGCTT/ && /GCGGCCGC$/ {arr[$0]++} END {for (i in arr) {print i "\t" arr[i]}}' file
```

> Explanation: find lines beginning with the first adapter and ending with the last adapter, then load these into an array and print the unique lines followed by the count for each line

With this test data:

```
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCGGCGGCCGC
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCGGCGGCCGC
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAcggtcaaaaaaaaCGGCGGCCGC
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCGGCGGCCGCAACT
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAcggtcaaaaaaaaCGGCGGCCGC
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAcggtcaaaaaaaaCccccccccc
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCGGCGGCCGC
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAcggtcaaaaaaaaCGGCGGCCGC
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCGGCGGCCGC
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCGGCGGCCGC
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAcggtcaaaaaaaaCGGCGGCCGC
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAcggtcaaaaaaaaCccccccccc
```

The output is:

```
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAAAGATGATGAGTTCGGCGGCCGC   5
AAGCTTCTGCCCACACACCGAAACATGAATCGATCACATACTAGAATCAGGCAGTCAGAGATATCAcggtcaaaaaaaaCGGCGGCCGC   4
```

If you just want the count, you can use `print arr[i]` instead of `print i "\t" arr[i]`, or if you want the count before the read you can use `print arr[i] "\t" i`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some file `dna.txt` you could simply:

1. Separate your original continuous DNA string into multiple lines, using your `PREFIX` as a line delimiter, then simply remove all the suffixes and all irrelevant DNA following them
2. Then use `sort -u` to iterate through all lines in your new file with no repeats (All the unique patterns).
3. Then simply use `grep -o` and `wc -l` to count the occurrences!

```sh
PREFIX='AAGCTT'
SUFFIX='GCGGCCGC'
find_traits() {
        # Step 1
        sed "s/${PREFIX}/\n/g" dna.txt > /tmp/dna_lines.txt
        sed -i "s/${SUFFIX}.*//" /tmp/dna_lines.txt

        # Step 2
        for pattern in $(sort -u /tmp/dna_lines.txt)
        do
                # Step 3
                printf "
PATTERN [$(grep -o $pattern dna.txt | wc -l)] : |${PREFIX}|${pattern}|${SUFFIX}|

"
        done
}
```